# Create array in unity C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am artist and I want to create a game.
I have a code in JS, and when I convert to C# this code can not work. Please help me. 
This is the code :

```
#pragma strict
var numberOfTiles = 8;
var tileObjects : GameObject[];

var tileLocations = new Array
(
    Vector3 (-4.44,3.2,0), Vector3 (-2.7,3.2,0), Vector3 (-0.9,3.2,0), Vector3 (0.95,3.2,0),    Vector3 (2.76,3.2,0), Vector3 (4.56,3.2,0), Vector3 (6.3,3.2,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,1.3,0), Vector3 (-2.7,1.3,0), Vector3 (-0.9,1.3,0), Vector3 (0.95,1.3,0), Vector3 (2.76,1.3,0), Vector3 (4.56,1.3,0), Vector3 (6.3,1.3,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-0.4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-0.4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-0.4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-0.4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-0.4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-0.4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-0.4,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-2.4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-2.4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-2.4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-2.4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-2.4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-2.4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-2.4,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-4,0)
);
```

Comment: `var tileLocations = new Vector3[] {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this format:

```
var tileLocations = new Vector3[] {         
    new Vector3 (-4.44,3.2,0), 
    new Vector3 (-2.7,3.2,0), 
     ... 
}
```

The '[]' is what makes it an array, of type Vector3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax is

```
int numberOfTiles = 8;    // <- var is superfluous here, put it like int
GameObject[] tileObjects; // <- Seems that you want to declare GameObject[]

var tileLocations = new Vector3[] // <- Vector3[], not Array
(
    Vector3 (-4.44,3.2,0), Vector3 (-2.7,3.2,0), Vector3 (-0.9,3.2,0), Vector3 (0.95,3.2,0),    Vector3 (2.76,3.2,0), Vector3 (4.56,3.2,0), Vector3 (6.3,3.2,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,1.3,0), Vector3 (-2.7,1.3,0), Vector3 (-0.9,1.3,0), Vector3 (0.95,1.3,0), Vector3 (2.76,1.3,0), Vector3 (4.56,1.3,0), Vector3 (6.3,1.3,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-0.4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-0.4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-0.4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-0.4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-0.4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-0.4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-0.4,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-2.4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-2.4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-2.4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-2.4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-2.4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-2.4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-2.4,0),
    Vector3 (-4.44,-4,0), Vector3 (-2.7,-4,0), Vector3 (-0.9,-4,0), Vector3 (0.95,-4,0), Vector3 (2.76,-4,0), Vector3 (4.56,-4,0), Vector3 (6.3,-4,0)
);
```

Another issue of the code that you actually *don't want*

```
  int numberOfTiles = 8;
```

since whenever you need you may call

```
  tileLocations.Length; // <- Length of the array i.e. number of tiles
```